# laravel 8 don't run migrate file in packages folder

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-8, database-migration

When run 'php artisan migrate' in windows os: laravel migrate all file (\database\migrations in root folder and in packages folder).
But in Linux os just migrate file in \database\migrations of root folder.
I have Database\migrations folder in packages folder and use the loadMigrationsFrom method in function boot() of service provider class.
How do I can migrate all files in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

You can give path to your migrate function like

```
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/packages
```

Comment: so why is there a difference in the two OS?

Comment: I do not know exactly, but this code should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do it right now is to manually go through all the migrations. You have to run the migration command on each of your sub-folders:

> php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/folder_name*

or you can add this to boot method in AppServiceProvider:

> $mainPath = database_path('migrations'); $directories = glob($mainPath
> . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR); $paths = array_merge([$mainPath],
> $directories);
>
> $this->loadMigrationsFrom($paths);